# Avoid duplicated code when rewriting Scan and Value methods in each type when usign go sql

Tags: go, gorp

Golan SQL plus Gorp expect that all types include a Scan and Value method attached to the type in order to read the Rows to a struct. This is adding a lot of boilerplate code in my project even when the methods can be generalized because I am writing JSON to this columns.

```
type Type1 struct {
 Type2 Type2
 Type3 Type3
 Type4 Type4
}

type Type2 struct { some primitives... }
type Type3 struct { some primitives... }
type Type4 struct { some primitives... }


func (q Type2) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(q)
}

func (q *Type2) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    source, _ := src.([]byte)
    if string(source) == "null" {
        return nil
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(source, q)
}

func (q Type3) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(q)
}

func (q *Type3) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    source, _ := src.([]byte)
    if string(source) == "null" {
        return nil
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(source, q)
}

func (q Type4) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(q)
}

func (q *Type4) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    source, _ := src.([]byte)
    if string(source) == "null" {
        return nil
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(source, q)
}
```

Is there a way to avoid defining all those identical Value and Scan Methods for each of my Structs?

The table should look like this:

```
Table: Type1
-----------------------
ROW   Type2                Type3               Type4
1     {"name": "MyName"}   {"other": "bla"}    {"other": "bla"}
```

I tried using composition as @danicheeta recommend:

```
type Base struct {} 
type Type2 struct { Base, some primitives... }

func (q Base) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(q)
}

func (q *Base) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    source, _ := src.([]byte)
    if string(source) == "null" {
        return nil
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(source, q)
}
```

But if I execute an insert to the database the result is:

```
Table: Type1
-----------------------
ROW   Type2                Type3               Type4
1     {}                   {}                  {}
```

Similarly if I have already inserted "manually" in the database this:

```
Table: Type1
    -----------------------
    ROW   Type2                Type3               Type4
    1     {"name": "MyName"}   {"other": "bla"}    {"other": "bla"}
```

And try to do a `select * from Type1` I get:

```
Type1: {
   Type2: {}
   Type3: {}
   Type4: {}
}
```

Comment: Do your types have only non-exported fields? Only exported fields will be serialized to json.

Comment: Nop, all are exported fields. And if I duplicate the code as shown it works. If I try to compose using the Base struct as mentioned by @danicheeta I get empty data.

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution:

```
type Base struct {}

type Type2 struct { Base, some primitives... }
type Type3 struct { Base, some primitives... }
type Type4 struct { Base, some primitives... }

func (q Base) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(q)
}

func (q *Base) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    source, _ := src.([]byte)
    if string(source) == "null" {
        return nil
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(source, q)
}
```

notice that Base embeded in structs should not have a var before it (i mean `type Type2 struct { b Base, some primitives... }`)

Comment: Hi @danicheeta, I already tested that but It does't work. I guess the SQL library in Go uses reflection to read the types of this Scan and Value function so it returns a wrong Json where the Marshal and Unmarshal is executed in the Base class and not in the Type2, Type3, Type4.

Comment: no, it simply calls scan in [here](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/convert.go#L341)
,can you give more info about the error ? put a panic in begining of scan to see if its even being called

Comment: Thanks for the reply @danicheeta, the main problem is not in golang SQL but because when adding the new Base struct it breake my JSON transformation. I elaborated the question putting some examples.

Comment: This will not work because the embedded struct `Base` cannot access the other fields of the embedding structs `Type2`, `Type3`, and `Type4`. Because struct embedding is composition and not inheritance, `Type2` (and the others) _has a_ `Base`, but _is NOT a_ `Base`. Calling `Type2.Value()` resolves to `Type2.Base.Value()` which only has access to the `Base` value. It returns an empty json string `{}` simply because the `Base` value does not have any fields. Try adding a dummy exported field to the `Base` struct and see if it gets serialized.

Comment: @SamChoukri yes, exactly that is what happens. So returning to the original question, is there a way to avoid all that code duplication? Maybe is just my stubbornness coming from functional or POO languages that I feel that I should get rid of all those duplicated methods... :)

Comment: @rsan You can use `go generate` to automate the creation of the nearly duplicate methods (probably not worth it for just a few types). Or wait for generics coming in Go 2.0.

Comment: Sam is right, the whole approach was wrong. came up with an idea using interfaces. are you comfortable using it in your struct ?